# Horizontal container's items alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to horizontally align/stack a container's items with a bootstrap technology without specifying bootstrap's columns. I would like to present one item after another, and only when not fit within a screen size, it should stack down each item, starting from the last one presented (the furthest on the right).
Here is what I am after:

```html
    <div>
        <div>
            <span class="">Some label</span>
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my initial bootstrap version that does not work:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23713/

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="">Some Label</span>
            <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean inline like this? http://bootply.com/ORId7643P4

Comment: that is perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `form-inline` like this..

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="">Some Label</span>
        <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/ORId7643P4

Answer (score 0):

use grid layout class. eg: `col-md-*`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Some Label</label>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default " />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, it is using grid columns and I don't like that in this example, it doesn't produce desired result, thanks though. @ZimSystem responded with valid option

Comment: But for horizontal form, every example use grid system. Otherwise you need to override lot of css